# Sublime 3 Mac - installing Babel for REACT

Tags: sublimetext3, babeljs

I am trying to install Babel for Sublime 3 so that I can get full text highlighting.

First, I went here [Sublime package control][1]

to install package control for Sublime. I did the "simple" install on the left. I believe I was successful but I am not sure how to check to see if it worked as planned. Then I could not find where to actually install Babel itself. If I understand correctly, "package control" simply gives me the power to install various packages, but does not contain packages itself. If you click around a bit on this site, you end up just going in circles and it never tells you clearly how to actually install Babel. I do know that it is NOT installed on my machine.

Comment: I am not sure why the link didn't work. Here's the address for the package control: https://packagecontrol.io/installation

Answer (score 0):

Package control installs everything you need. After it is installed change display syntax for the file in right bottom corner from javascript to babel